# VBA Excel - copy range from a second file to a vba-range object

Tags: vba, excel

i wanted to write a excel-vba module accessing date from second excel-file.
i first wanted to open the second file to a vba-range object, copy the worksheet-range to a vba-range-object and close the second file afterwards.

data-processing now happens only on the vba-range object.

i tried the following:

```
Set oMeasuresWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sMeasuresFileName)
Set oSrcRange = oMeasuresWorkbook.Names("MEASURES").RefersToRange
MsgBox oSrcRange(1, 1)
oMeasuresWorkbook.Close

'problem: after closing the second file (oMeasuresWorkbook) the
          oSrcRange Object is gone
MsgBox oSrcRange(1, 1) 'error here as the oSrcRange Object is gone
```

everything works fine until i close the second file. seemingly, oSrcRange is a reference to the original data. btw. same behavior if i access the range by for eg.

Set oSrcRange = oMeasuresWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:G")

So how would I "deep copy" the range. i tried range.copy but semmingly i do not know how i would initialize a range object (and i do not want to copy the data to a worksheet).

i hope i made myself clear and sombody can help

thanx !

Comment: not so sure I understand, you want to `Copy` the `oSrcRange` after you Close the `oMeasuresWorkbook` ? Why not copy it before you `Close` it ?

Comment: you should use arrays , your code will run a lot faster. And if you still wanna copy data as you said above you should use vector(after you op the 2'nd file, you need to store the data from the second excel file in the vector and then you can close your 2 excel file), after that you can play with the vector as you wish.......but my recomandation it's to use arrays for what you need

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```
Dim SrcRangeArray as Variant
Set oMeasuresWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sMeasuresFileName)
Set oSrcRange = oMeasuresWorkbook.Names("MEASURES").RefersToRange
SrcRangeArray = oSrcRange.Value
MsgBox SrcRangeArray (1, 1)
oMeasuresWorkbook.Close

'problem: after closing the second file (oMeasuresWorkbook) the oSrcRange Object is gone
MsgBox SrcRangeArray (1, 1)
```

As far as I know, there isn't a way to store a copy of an Object solely in memory where it is then no longer affected by changes to the original object. Objects are storing actual objects, and not the values of those objects.

In my code above, I instead take the value from the range and put it into an array. These values will persist, even if the original object is closed. Note though that you can now only work on those values. You can't 'Close' or 'Open' the array for example, since it is just values.

I left the original object there for demonstration, but if you dont need the object, and you do only need its values, I would just skip the middleman and go with the array instead.